# Why the total space of $\mathcal{O}(K)$ has trivial canonical bundle?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

Let $X$ be a smooth variety, and $K$ be the canonical divisor on $X$. Let $\mathcal{O}(K)$ be the corresponding canonical sheaf. Then why the total space $Spec\mathcal{O}(K)$ has trivial canonical bundle?

Comment: Is $X$ smooth projective?

Comment: Yes, it is smooth.

Comment: This is very intriguing: why do you think it is true ?

Comment: I read something closed to that in the paper "http://arxiv.org/pdf/hep-th/9309097.pdf" (Page 62, last 6 lines). That paper deal with toric case, but I also heard from people that the above method is a way of constructing non-compact calabi-Yau variety

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $Y$ be a total space of $\omega_X$
$$
Y=\operatorname{Spec} \oplus_{i \geq 0} \omega_X^{-i}.
$$
and $\pi: Y \to X$ is projection of this vector bundle. I fix some nowhere vanishing section $s$ of $\omega_X$ over an affine chart $Spec(A)=U \subset X$ and use canonical identification
$$
T_{vert}^* \cong \omega_X^{-1},
$$
to conclude that $s \wedge s^{-1}$ is a section of $\omega_Y$ over $\pi^{-1}(U) \cong Spec(A[s])$. Other choice of section will differ by nowhere vanishing function and this differences does not affect $s \wedge s^{-1}$, i.e. $s \wedge s^{-1}$ is a trivializing section of $\omega_Y$.

Comment: Thank you! But I have a few questions: (1) Isn't the total space of $\omega_X$   $Spec \oplus_{i\geq 0}\omega^i_X$ (i.e. the symmetric algebra of $\omega_X$)? I don't understand where the negative power comes from. (2) Why the vertical tangent bundle is $\omega_X$? (3) Why $s\wedge s^{-1}$ is a global section of $\omega_Y$?

Comment: (1) No, I want to get ring of polynomial functions on a vector space space that means that I have to take symmetric algebra of a dual space. For example, dual space is exactly linear functions etc. More generally, if I want total space of a vector bundle I have to take symmetric algebra of dual vector bundle.(2) This is the same idea: if we take symmetric algebra on a vector space what is cotangent bundle canonically?

Comment: (3) $s \wedge s^{-1}$ is not a global section! It is a section over one affine chart. But if you choose another affine chart (that intersects first) transition function for two section is identity, and so you can glue them together and then continue with next affine chart.

Comment: I understand (1) now! Could you say something more on (2)? Especially, I don't know how to distinguish the vertical tangent bundle from the tangent bundle(I can imagine this), and I still don't get what you claimed. (3)I understand it is not a global section. Suppose on an affine piece, you basically use $\Omega_{A[t]} \cong \Omega_A \oplus dt$, am I right?

Comment: (2) Over affine chart bundle is trivial, cotangent bundle to $X$ gives horizontal part, cotangent bundle to the fiber is vertical part. Perhaps it is easier to think first about one point. Over a point $x$ fiber is $(\omega_X)_x$, cotangent space to fiber is dual to this  space. I do the same in my answer, but for the whole affine chart, identifying cotangent bundle to the fibers with $\omega_X^{-1}$. I think about this as a family of vector spaces $\omega_X$ over $U$ and then I identify cotangent spaces with dual spaces of the family.

Comment: (3) If I think about $s$ as $dx_1 \wedge \ldots \wedge dx_2$ then a need one more local coordinate (in the fiber) to take wedge product of $s$ and $d$ of that local coordinate to get a section of $\omega_Y$. But by (2) a can just take $s^{-1}$.

Comment: Comments to Alex's solution: Because $\omega_Y = \det((T_{vert}+T_{hor})^*) = \det((T_{vert}^{*}))\otimes \det(T_{hor})^*) = \omega_X^{-1}\otimes \omega_X = \mathcal{O}_Y$.